# How to check whether an enum variable is assigned with a single enum value?

Tags: c#

I would like to restrict the user to use any of the enumvalue.if the user tries to assign more than two values,i have to throw an error.

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Grapes
}

public Fruits Fruits
{
    get
    {
        return m_fruits;
    }
    set
    {
        m_fruits=value;
    }
}

Fruits = Fruits.Apple & Fruits.Grapes; //I need to avoid such type of assignment
```

Can anyone say how to check this type of validation.

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: Nothing technical but NOT using plural while naming properties help other developers that it is not intended to use as bit flags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Enum.IsDefined` to see whether an integral value is actually defined for an enum. In order to be able to detect that no logical operation such as `Fruits.Apple | Fruits.Grapes` has been used make sure that your enum values are flags.

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple = 1,
    Orange = 2,
    Grapes = 4
}

public Fruits Fruit
{
    get
    {
        return m_fruits;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Fruits), value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        m_fruits = value;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

A faster method without reflection would be to check all enum values yourself:

```
public Fruits Fruit
{
    get
    {
        return m_fruits;
    }
    set
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case Fruits.Apple:
            case Fruits.Grapes:
            case Fruits.Orange:
                m_fruits = value;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't like it, really. `IsDefined` involves fat reflection and it is slow. It is really easier to use class like `Encodings` where there are static fields with instances.

Comment: @Andrey: True that `IsDefined` uses reflection and is not the fastest. When using an enum the only other method you have is to explicitly check all defined values, e.g. using a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Enum.IsDefined()` method to check whether a value is a valid enum value:

```
Fruits f1 = Fruits.Orange;
Fruits f2 = (Fruits)77;

var b1 = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Fruits), f1); // => true
var b2 = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Fruits), f2); // => false
```

---

BTW: Your example seems incorrect: `var f = Fruits.Apple&Fruits.Grapes` will assign `Fruits.Apple` to `f`. This is because a bitwise AND of Apple (==0) and Grapes (==2) will result in 0 (which still is a valid enum value -> Apple).

If you meant something like `var f = Fruits.Orange|Fruits.Grapes`, then f will now be **3** (bitwise OR of 1 and 2) and `Enum.IsDefined` will now return false.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bitwise operation, and can only be used in conjunction with the `[Flags]` attribute, and when you're values for your enum are explicitly applicable to flags (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.)

Comment: IIRC the [Flags] attribute is only for diagnostics (BTW I don't recommend omitting it).

Comment: @Richard-->Thanks,I have tried of adding such thisngs.If the user used ' | ' instead of '&' then the value will be returned would be some 6 (for example) which given annoying results.

Comment: No, what you need to do is not have the `[Flags]` attribute, and then you should be fine, because, as Fredrik said, if its not marked with the `[Flags]` attribute, then any bitwise operation will return 0.

Comment: @Richard: You can use bitwise operation no matter whether the `[Flags]` attribute is present or not.  It just *indicates* that the enumeration contains flags. Of course, bitwise operation only make sense if the enum is declared with meaningful values (i.e. constants in powers of two).

Comment: @Richard: "then any bitwise operation will return 0" - This is not correct.

Comment: What the [Flags] attribute *will* do however, is to change how any composite value is formatted as a string - either using ToString() or the debugger. If you have an enum with values a=1 and b=2, and a variable of that type with a value of 3, without the [Flags] attribute you will get "3", with it you'll get "a | b" (in the debugger) or "a, b" (from ToString()).

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict it. The only way to do it to create custom class and create static fields with instances (like `Encoding`). By the way, bitwise & is meaningless for `enum` that is not marked as `[Flags]`. `Fruits.Apple&Fruits.Grapes` will not set two values (`|` does), it will produce meaningless result: since by default enums are mapped to sequence of ints `Fruits.Apple&Fruits.Grapes` will produce `Fruits.Apple` because `Apple` is mapped to 0